# How to find that if a user is present on the nodes using chef

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Is there any search pattern  by which we can find that a particular user is present on which nodes using chef.I looked around the knife search patterns and didn't found any way.
This task however is  very simple with use of ansible.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of attributes populated by ohai. see [this](http://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-sources) and [this](http://docs.chef.io/ohai.html)

You can see a list of attributes with `knife node show NODENAME -l`

The search documentation is [here](https://docs.chef.io/knife_search.html#)

And it says each key is indexed at top level, users are under `node['etc']['passwd']` attribute so the command you're looking for is `knife search node 'passwd:username'`